# Pattern Match Timed-out

Tags: regex, perl, telnet

I use Perl Net::telnet for connecting to my router and change some options, but i get this error:

> pattern match timed-out

every thing is true (user , pass , pattern and etc), i am going crazy for the source of this error. my code is:

```
use Net::Telnet;
$telnet = new Net::Telnet ( Timeout=>10, Errmode=>'die');
$telnet->open('192.168.1.1');
$telnet->waitfor('/login[: ]$/i');
$telnet->print('admin');
$telnet->waitfor('/password[: ]$/i');
$telnet->print('admin');
$telnet->waitfor('/\$ $/i' );
$telnet->print('list');
$output = $telnet->waitfor('/\$ $/i');
print $output;
```

What should i do now? Is there any alternative way?
Thank you

Comment: Are those strings you are passing to `waitfor`, are they regular expressions ?

Comment: yeah, when i connected to my router(admin,admin) i get this $ for entering command

Comment: @michael:what you mean?

Comment: Which pattern is timing out? If you execute this manually, does it work as expected? Are you sure that the command prompt is exactly `$` followed by exactly one space?

Comment: @rutter:Yeah, That's true i used "('/\$$/i' )" instead of "('/\$ $/i' )" and it's work.

Comment: @user2676574 ,  disable firewall or view system logs to see if any connection is being blocked.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try logging in using the example at the top of [Net::Telnet](http://search.cpan.org/~jrogers/Net-Telnet-3.04/lib/Net/Telnet.pm) page?

```
use Net::Telnet ();
$t = new Net::Telnet (Timeout => 10, Errmode=>'die');
$t->open($host);
$t->login($username, $passwd);
@lines = $t->cmd("who");
print @lines;
```

That seems to work for me.  While your code snippet times out at the first `waitfor` trying to login.

Comment: Do you have any alternative way? not use Net::Telnet()

Comment: Hmm, and you can telnet into your router manually without problem?

Comment: Try using dump_log() to see why it's timing out.  (See the Net::Telnet link.)